# Multiple Joins in the Same Row

Tags: mysql, database, join

I'm a little lost on the following. So I have two tables.

Table1 (Contains score of students)

```
Students  English  Chemistry
Jack        3         2
Jane        2         8
Jill        6         1
```

Table2 (Contains Grading Criteria)

```
 Begin    Finish      Grade
  0          4          C
  5          7          B
  8          10         A
```

The final result I want is,

```
  Student     English   Chemistry 
  Jack        C           C
  Jane        B           A
  Jill        B           C
```

I'm guessing there are two joins, but I'm not sure how to exactly implement that. I can do for a single column, meaning I can get the result for one subject by following

```
SELECT table1.Student, table2.Grade FROM table1,table2 WHERE (table1.English>=table2.Begin and table1.English<=table2.Finish);
```

But I don't know how to do it so I get grades for both the subjects in one table and the same row.

Comment: Consider notmaling your data. A table is NOT a spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select Students.name,
      gc1.Grade as EnglishGrade,
      gc2.grade as ChemistryGrade
from students 
join GradeCriteria gc1 on Students.English between gc1.begin and gc1.finish
join GradeCriteria gc2 on Students.Chemistry between gc2.begin and gc2.finish
order by 1
```

Only one GradeCriteria table, but we need to reference it twice in the query, so we add an alias to the table name so SQL knows which version of the table you are referring to.  The GC1 alias says show me the rows where the students English score matches the criteria.   The GC2 alias says, use the same table, but show me the rows where the Chemistry score matches the criteria...

Comment: Hey, thank you for the reply. I'm a little confused here, what is gc2? and gc1? I'm assuming grade criteria? But, I only have one table with grade criteria right?

Comment: You can reference the same table multiple times, the gc1 and gc2 are aliases to refer to the table by.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, but how does MySQL know that I am referring to table2 when I mentioned gc1 and gc2.

Comment: Think of SQL queries as a tool to create "mini" tables (result sets).  You want all of the rows from students (Students table).   For each student's English column, you want to create a mini table (result set) to get the row that corresponds to his English score.   For each student's chemistry grade, you want to create  a second mini table (result set) that corresponds to his Chemistry score

Comment: @LeRay Did it solved your problem? If yes, pls accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could also consider eliminating the table 2 and instead using a case statement with a query on table 1.